# How do I make a transition for an image in a div class without affecting the text?

Tags: html, css

I want the image opacity set to 1 when I hover over the div class, but I don't want to affect the icon or h3. How can I directly select what the transition is affecting when I hover over the div/column. 
I just need some help with the css, what do I need to do to make maybe the hover distance larger in height and width.

Or better yet how do I make the transition for the div only affect the images inside?

I should preface this by saying I am new to html and css. I have tried making it so that when I hover over the image it goes to 1 in opacity. I want the opacity to change to 1 when I hover over the div/column without changing the opacity of the text in the div/column.

```
<section class="projects clearfix" id="projs">
            <div class="row">
                <h2>H2 Text</h2>
            </div>

            <ul class="showcase">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
                            <figure class="photo">
                                <i class="ion-ios-checkmark-circle big-icon"></i>
                                <h3>Complete Intelligence</h3>
                                <img src="resources/css/img/test.png" alt="placeholder" class="work-img" id="testing">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

I haven't received any errors, so far my results have been what I was expecting. Just need some help with css for this.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out. lmao. I'm so stupid, it was a simple fix. 
All I had to do was this:

```
.showcase .col:hover img{
opacity: 1;
}
```